# Nested Bootstrap Collapse (Accordion)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I'm implementing Bootstrap 3.3.7 Collapse (accordion). I did copy the example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse).

I modified the panel-title part by adding caret and moving the text out of anchor so that only caret would clickable that would respond to the collapse event:

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-role-1_sub-role-1-accordion" href="#collapse-sub-role-1_sub-role-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-sub-role-1_sub-role-1">
        <span class="caret caret-mr"></span>
    </a>Sub Role 1
</h4>
```

I also added custom JS and CSS to make caret go up (dropup) when clicked to collapse:

```
var collapseList = $('.panel .panel-collapse');
collapseList.each(function() {
    var collapseId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + collapseId).on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
        $(this).prev('.panel-heading').find('.panel-title > a').addClass('dropup');
    }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
        $(this).prev('.panel-heading').find('.panel-title > a').removeClass('dropup');
    });
});

.panel .panel-heading>.panel-title>a>span.caret {
    border-top: 6px solid black;
}

.panel .panel-heading>.panel-title>a.dropup>span.caret {
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
    border-top: none;
}
```

I've changed all the IDs and all others data-attributes to avoid conflicts.

This perfectly works except for nested accordion (accordion inside an accordion body). Currently, I have three levels of nested accordion. The problem is that the nested accordion affects also the parent up to the root accordion - their carets also go dropup or dropdown. The second accordion (nested) affects the first, the third affects the second and first.

Complete codes: [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/julianjupiter/94c2e71f523e65376931c9333d787062)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you need custom JavaScript? Bootstrap marks the active collapsable.

Comment: To answer your question, I think it's because those 2 events bubble, so you need `function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); }` before doing your logic.

Comment: I did not write the JS for collapsible purpose but for modifying the position of caret, from down to up and the other way around.

Comment: That's what I mean by 'mark' :) You can style it in any way you want without having a custom class because Bootstrap marks it for you anyway. Check Manish's answer.

Comment: dropup and caret are both Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
collapseList.each(function() {
var collapseId = $(this).attr('id');
$('#' + collapseId).on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-heading').find('.panel-title > a').addClass('dropup');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).prev('.panel-heading').find('.panel-title > a').removeClass('dropup');
});
 });
```

You can try this , if not fixed please share the html code for panel you have written.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code to no available. Please take a look at my HTML code: https://gist.github.com/julianjupiter/94c2e71f523e65376931c9333d787062

Comment: Hey,I don't think any condition need to check here. Just have a look into this and let me know if it  solved your question. https://jsfiddle.net/8dL80u7g/

Answer (score 1):

```css
span[aria-expanded="true"] i::before {
        content: "\f106";
    }

    .uner {
        margin: 0 50px 15px;
    }
    #collapse1 {
        border:1px solid #dedede;
        border-top:0px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
        <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a>Collapsible Group 1</a>
                        <span class="pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a>Sub Collapsible Group 1.1</a>
                                    <span class="pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a>Sub Collapsible Group 1.2</a>
                                    <span class="pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></div>
                            </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: does it work with version 4? if not can you please let me know how to do the same thing using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

***Update 2021***

The original answers are out-of-date. With the latest **Bootstrap 5**, [accordion behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/#always-open) can be acheived by simply using the `data-bs-parent=` attribute on the sibling Collapse elements...

Nested accordions can be placed inside another Collapse element which then becomes the `data-bs-parent=` of the nested children.

```
<div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0 d-inline">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> Collapse #1 </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body" id="child1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOneA">Child A</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#child1" id="collapseOneA"> ... </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOneB">Child B</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#child1" id="collapseOneB"> ... </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"> Collapse #2 </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body"> ... </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"> Collapse #3 </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body"> ... </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Bootstrap 5 Nested Accordion](https://codeply.com/p/lZdmM9pbfh#)